# MySQL query. Select data from three tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I have three tables:

**language**
(id,lang_name, published)

**translators**
(id, name,surname, phone, email, published)

**trans_lang_rel**(language and translator relation. one translator can translate from one or more languages)

id, trans_id, lang_id

**Data in tables:**

**language**

1 English 1
2 Russian 1
3 German  1

**translators**

1 Name1 Surname1 999 name1.surname1@gmail.com 1
2 Name2 Surname2 888 name2.surname2@gmail.com 1

**trans_lang_rel**

1 1 1
2 1 2
3 2 1

So I have to select data from these three tables.

Result should be like this:

Name1 | Surname1 | English,Russian | 999 | name1.surname1@gmail.com

I've tried something like this but I got strange results:

```
SELECT t.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(l.lang_name SEPARATOR ", ") AS language 
FROM translators AS t, 
trans_lang_rel AS tlr 
LEFT JOIN language AS l ON l.id = tlr.lang_id ORDER BY t.id
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT  t.name,
        t.surname,
        GROUP_CONCAT(l.lang_name SEPARATOR ", "),
        t.phone,
        t.email
FROM    translators t INNER JOIN
        trans_lang_rel tlr  ON  t.id = tlr. trans_id INNER JOIN
        language l  ON  tlr.lang_id = l.id
GROUP BY    t.name,
            t.surname,
            t.phone,
            t.email
```

Answer (score 0):

the way you have joined translator and trna_lang_rel wasn't good. You made a `full join` since you never but any `ON` clause

```
SELECT t.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(l.lang_name SEPARATOR ", ") AS language 
FROM translators t 
JOIN trans_lang_rel tlr ON t.id = trans_id
LEFT JOIN language AS l ON l.id = tlr.lang_id
ORDER BY t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  translators.name,
  translators.surname,
  GROUP_CONCAT(language.name SEPARATOR ", ") AS language,
  translators.phone,
  translators.email
FROM
  translators
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  trans_lang_rel
ON
  trans_lang_rel.trans_id = translators.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  language
ON
  trans_lang_rel.lang_id = language.id
```